# GRUB2 Hide partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a multiboot (Windows 95/98/Me) system running using a boot manager called 'System Commander'. The windows installs each have a separate partition.

I've managed to install Ubuntu onto the fourth partition, but unfortunately, 'System Commander' does not seem to like Linux operating systems at all.

I thought of using GRUB2, but I can only boot into a Windows partition after making it active. I can switch between Ubuntu or one specific Windows partition, even though all Windows installs are in the list.

The reason is (I think) because Windows 9x systems require the drive to be mapped to C (which is the one that is marked as active if I remember correctly).

Can I hide the other partitions to force each Windows install to boot? This is basically the same as how 'System Commander' works as far as I can tell.

I've found [this post](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=51335) which is exactly what I need, but it's for grub4dos. I really want to use GRUB2 if possible since it's more modern and maybe I could reuse some stuff afterwards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

You need to edit the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file. In the Windows 9x sections (which were automatically detected), add this command:

```
parttool (hd0,X) boot+
```

where X is the partition with the specific Windows install you want to boot. This sets the correct partition as active, thus it will be mapped as drive C. Edit all the Win 9x entries you have with the correct partition number.

Leave everything else default.

This is just a temporary fix and will be lost after running update-grub, so I recommend making a backup of the grub.cfg file so you can easily copy it back in case your Win 9x entries stopped working after an update.